# Biomedcentral figure caption outside bounding box

Tags: graphics, floats, captions

When using the BioMed Central template (`bmcart` documentclass) the figure caption overflows the figures bounding box. How can this be fixed?

```
\begin{figure}[hbtp]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{myfig}
\caption{\csentence{my long caption text}.\label{fig:myfig}}}
\end{figure}
```

As an example, here's how the figure looks in the pdf (I've hidden the text):

[image: Overflowing caption figure]

This is the document class:

```
\documentclass{bmcart}
```

Comment: Is the error unique to the `bmcart` class?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: I usually do not get the overflowing caption if I use other document classes.

Comment: Do you use the subfigure package?

Comment: No, just as in the code snippet in the question. I did find a temporary workaround by adding \\ at various places in the caption text.